# How to make 'wavy' effect in Photoshop / Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm looking to find a way to apply the 'wavy' effect to text / image in either Photoshop or Illustrator. The example of what I want to get is provided below.

[image: effect example]

Comment: @BillyKerr I've only tried twist effect in Illustrator, but it applies a simpler effect than in the sample image I've attached

Comment: Try using an [envelope instead](https://i.imgur.com/83auGye.png), 15 rows, and 1 column should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Warp tool solves the problem just fine[image]